# Copy XML and rename some of its nodes and nested nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to copy everything to new XML except some elements which I need to rename.

All "child" nodes which are childs of "node1" I need to rename to "children" and "child" nodes which are childs of "node2" I need to rename to "kid".

Perfect solution will be using

```
match="/root/node1/descendant::child"
```

But as I found in Michael Kay response in topic http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.saxon.help/14956

> A pattern of the form /descendant::m__id[1] is not legal in either
>   XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, though it becomes legal in XSLT 3.0.

Do You have any suggestions how to do that in XSLT 2.0 without doing what I made below? Because I don't know how many nesting there will be exactly.

Here is my xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <node1>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node2>
</root>
```

And XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/node1/child">
        <xsl:element name="children">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/node1/child/subnode/child">
        <xsl:element name="children">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/node2/child">
        <xsl:element name="kid">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/node2/child/subnode/child">
        <xsl:element name="kid">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `//child` in a pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/node1//child">
    <xsl:element name="children">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/root/node2//child">
    <xsl:element name="kid">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I would use literal result elements instead of xsl:element:

```
<xsl:template match="/root/node1//child">
    <children>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </children>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/root/node2//child">
    <kid>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </kid>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your solution also works fine for me. Thx for response.

Could You explain why to use literal result elements? 
I note only diffrence when using literal when I have to add exclude-result-prefixes to stylesheet tag because I use namespaces in files.

Comment: Using literal result elements you have to write less code and it is clearer in my view what the stylesheet does (e.g. map `node1//child` to `children`), I only use `xsl:element` when the name and/or namespace of an element needs to be computed at run-time.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <children>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </children>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child[ancestor::node2]">
    <kid>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </kid>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine on my original 10k line XML document. Thx for Ur solution.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution doesn't use any predicates or axes at all**, has the *shortest* match patterns, and thus is more efficient than one that uses predicates.

**It also produces the expected correct result when `<node1>` has descendents or ancestors `<node2>` -- something which the remaining solutions don't handle at all**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node1" mode="#all">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="node1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node2" mode="#all">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="node2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child" mode="node1">
    <children>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </children>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="child" mode="node2">
    <kid>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </kid>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node2>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
      <node1>
            <children>
                  <subnode>
                        <children/>
                  </subnode>
      </children>
            <children>
                  <subnode>
                        <children/>
                  </subnode>
      </children>
      </node1>
      <node2>
            <kid>
                  <subnode>
                        <kid/>
                  </subnode>
      </kid>
            <kid>
                  <subnode>
                        <kid/>
                  </subnode>
      </kid>
      </node2>
</root>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document, where `<node1>` and `<node2>` are descendents or ancestors of each other**:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <child>
            <subnode>
              <node2>
                  <child></child>
                  <node1>
                    <child/>
                  </node1>            
              </node2>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
        <node1>
            <child>
                <subnode>
                    <child></child>
                </subnode>
            </child>
        </node1>
        <child>
            <subnode>
                <child></child>
            </subnode>
        </child>
    </node2>
</root>
```

**again the correct and wanted result (the replacement-name of `<child>` is determined by its closest ancestor that is either `<node1>` or `<node2>`) is produced**:

```
<root>
      <node1>
            <children>
                  <subnode>
                     <node2>
                           <kid/>
                           <node1>
                              <children/>
                           </node1>           
                     </node2>
                  </subnode>
            </children>
            <children>
                  <subnode>
                        <children/>
                  </subnode>
            </children>
      </node1>
      <node2>
            <kid>
                  <subnode>
                        <kid/>
                  </subnode>
            </kid>
            <node1>
                  <children>
                        <subnode>
                              <children/>
                        </subnode>
                  </children>
            </node1>
            <kid>
                  <subnode>
                        <kid/>
                  </subnode>
            </kid>
      </node2>
</root>
```

Comment: In my original files I do not have situation where <node1> and <node2> are descendents or ancestors of each other but thanks for that example.

I have to read something about "mode" and I will apply Your solution to my original files to see how it works.

Comment: @Elej, I am glad that this answer solves not only your current problem, but also future problems :)  You are always welcome to ask further into this.